# Gurobi, C#: Can't convert from 'int' to System.Collections.Generic.List<int>

Tags: c#, gurobi

I'm trying to solve a scheduling problem on with `Gurobi` solver. 
I want to write my `Gurobi` solution into the console. I get an error saying

> "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to System.Collections.Generic.List'

This exact code worked for two other variables which is successfully wrote into the console.

Where is the error here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Gurobi;

List<List<List<int>>> X_ijk_list = new List<List<List<int>>>();

Console.WriteLine("X_ijk");

for (int k = 0; k < n_machines; ++k)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Maschine" + k);
    X_ijk_list.Add(new List<List<int>>());

    for (int i = 0; i < n_jobs; ++i)
    {
        X_ijk_list[i].Add(new List<int>());

        for (int j = 0; j < n_tasks_job[i]; ++j)
        {
            X_ijk_list[i].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X))); //error here
            Console.Write(X_ijk_list[i][j][k]);
            Console.Write(";");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 nested Lists. In this line:

```
X_ijk_list[i].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X))); //
```

you are trying to add a number into the first nested list. But if you take a look at your declaration:

```
List<List<List<int>>> X_ijk_list = new List<List<List<int>>>();
```

You will need a `List<int>` ! like you did already in this line:

```
X_ijk_list[i].Add(new List<int>());
```

Your solution would be to use the index `j` from the second loop and insert it into the second nested list:

```
X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X))); //
```

As you go deeper in your loops you need to go deeper into the nested lists:

```
X_ijk_list.Add(new List<List<int>>());
X_ijk_list[i].Add(new List<int>());
X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(3);
```

Comment: although I am sure there will be no comment on the downvote, I still gonna ask WHY?

Answer (score 1):

In you case `X_ijk_list[i]` is `List<List<int>>` how it could be noted from first line:

```
List<List<List<int>>> X_ijk_list
```

I guess there is typo error and you could get the desired behaviour with modifying this line as:

```
X_ijk_list[i][j].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List` of `List` of `List` of `int`. You try to `Add` an `int` element to the `i`'th `List`. Since your variable is a `List` of `List` of `List` of `int`, its `i`'th element is a `List` of `List` of `int`. When you try to `Add` something to it, the parameter to be added is expected to be a `List` of `int`. Since you pass an `int` instead, you get the error mentioned in the question. You need to add your `int` to the last element of the `i`'th element of your `List` of `List` of `List` of `int`:

```
X_ijk_list[i][X_ijk_list[i].Count() - 1].Add(Convert.ToInt32(X_ijk[i, j, k].Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X)));
```